# Finding the big O complexity for the following code

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=1;j<i*i;j++)
for(int k=1;k<j;k++)
    if (j % i==1)
        sum++;
```

The first statement is constant.
The first for loop takes n times.
The second for loop takes n^2 times.
The third for loop takes n times.
The if statement takes constant time.
The final statement takes constant time.

Thus final complexity is n x n^2 x n x n = O(n^4)

Is my understanding and final answer correct?

Comment: Is the third loop nested in the seconds loop? Maybe you have an indentation error.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of the third loop is O(n^2) since it is `k<j` and `j` will equal `i*i` (`n*n`). But the complexity of the example would be O(n^3) as you only multiply the time complexity if they are nested. Otherwise, for things occurring in sequence, their time complexity should be added O(1 + n^3 + n^2), which is simplified to the term of the highest order O(n^3) as with very large numbers this will be the only term that matters.

See this [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132331/what-is-o-and-how-do-i-calculate-it) for a more detailed answer, there are more resources there too.

```
int sum = 0;                  O(1)

for(int i=1;i<n;i++)          O(n)  
    for(int j=1;j<i*i;j++)    O(n^2)
                            = O(n^3)
  
for(int k=1;k<j;k++)          O(n^2)
    if (j % i==1)             O(1) 
        sum++;                O(1)
                            = O(n^2)

= O(1 + n^3 + n^2)
= O(n^3)
```

Comment: Unless there's a missing semicolon, the loops are ALL nested so it's O(n^5)